# Servlet.service() for servlet [FitbitApiAuthExampleServlet] in context with path [/Webfit]

Tags: eclipse, debugging, servlets, tomcat7

I'm having a problem.
I'm developing web application in Eclipse IDE and using Tomcat 7.

Everything was working fine, when suddenly my debugger doesn't work anymore as it should and everything collapsed to pieces. I was looking for same errors, but I haven't found soulution yet. Please help me.

I'm getting this error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FitbitApiAuthExampleServlet] in context with path [/Webfit] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(Unknown Source)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.encode(OAuth.java:254)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.encodeParameters(OAuth.java:233)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.encodeParameters(OAuth.java:217)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.normalizeRequestParameters(OAuth.java:196)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuth.java:85)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.OAuth.generateAuthorizationHeader(OAuth.java:129)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.HttpClient.setHeaders(HttpClient.java:522)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.HttpClient.httpRequest(HttpClient.java:422)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.http.HttpClient.get(HttpClient.java:398)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.FitbitApiClientAgent.httpGet(FitbitApiClientAgent.java:2563)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.FitbitApiClientAgent.httpGet(FitbitApiClientAgent.java:2513)
    at com.fitbit.api.client.FitbitApiClientAgent.getLoggedHeartRate(FitbitApiClientAgent.java:1779)
    at com.fitbit.web.FitbitApiAuthExampleServlet.doGet(FitbitApiAuthExampleServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Servlet code:

```
package com.fitbit.web;

import com.fitbit.api.FitbitAPIException;
import com.fitbit.api.client.*;
import com.fitbit.api.client.service.FitbitAPIClientService;
import com.fitbit.api.common.model.body.Body;
import com.fitbit.api.common.model.body.BodyWithGoals;
import com.fitbit.api.common.model.bp.Bp;
import com.fitbit.api.common.model.heart.Heart;
import com.fitbit.api.common.model.user.UserInfo;
import com.fitbit.api.model.APIResourceCredentials;
import com.fitbit.api.model.FitbitUser;


import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Kiryl
 * Date: 6/22/11
 * Time: 7:05 AM
 */
public class FitbitApiAuthExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public static final String OAUTH_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
    public static final String OAUTH_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";

    private FitbitAPIEntityCache entityCache = new FitbitApiEntityCacheMapImpl();
    private FitbitApiCredentialsCache credentialsCache = new FitbitApiCredentialsCacheMapImpl();
    private FitbitApiSubscriptionStorage subscriptionStore = new FitbitApiSubscriptionStorageInMemoryImpl();

    private String apiBaseUrl;
    private String fitbitSiteBaseUrl;
    private String exampleBaseUrl;
    private String clientConsumerKey;
    private String clientSecret;

    private FitbitUser fitbitUser = new FitbitUser("-");

    private int year = 2012;
    private int month = 5;
    private int day = 5;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        try {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
            apiBaseUrl = properties.getProperty("apiBaseUrl");
            fitbitSiteBaseUrl = properties.getProperty("fitbitSiteBaseUrl");
            exampleBaseUrl = properties.getProperty("exampleBaseUrl").replace("/app", "");
            clientConsumerKey = properties.getProperty("clientConsumerKey");
            clientSecret = properties.getProperty("clientSecret");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ServletException("Exception during loading properties", e);
        }

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        FitbitAPIClientService<FitbitApiClientAgent> apiClientService = new FitbitAPIClientService<FitbitApiClientAgent>(
                new FitbitApiClientAgent(apiBaseUrl, fitbitSiteBaseUrl, credentialsCache),
                clientConsumerKey,
                clientSecret,
                credentialsCache,
                entityCache,
                subscriptionStore
        );
        if (request.getParameter("completeAuthorization") != null) {
            // Get temporary token and verifier returned by Fitbit from query string
            String tempTokenReceived = request.getParameter(OAUTH_TOKEN);
            String tempTokenVerifier = request.getParameter(OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            // Fetch user credentials from cache by temporary token from query string
            APIResourceCredentials resourceCredentials = apiClientService.getResourceCredentialsByTempToken(tempTokenReceived);

            /*Handle error when there is no record of credentials in cache for the temporary token provided
            As implementation of the credentials cache in this example is not persistant,
            this error will popup if you restart application, while user's browser will be on Fitbit*/           
            if (resourceCredentials == null) {
                throw new ServletException("Unrecognized temporary token when attempting to complete authorization: " + tempTokenReceived);
            }

            // Call method of Fitbit4J to get token credentials only if necessary (they haven't been cached yet)
            if (!resourceCredentials.isAuthorized()) {                
                resourceCredentials.setTempTokenVerifier(tempTokenVerifier);    // The verifier token is required in the request to get token credentials
                try {                    
                    apiClientService.getTokenCredentials(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()));    // get token credentials for user
                } catch (FitbitAPIException e) {
                    throw new ServletException("Unable to finish authorization with Fitbit.", e);
                }
            }
            try {
                // get UserInfo             
                UserInfo userInfo = apiClientService.getClient().getUserInfo(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()));
                request.setAttribute("userInfo", userInfo);

                //get HeartRate
                Heart heartInfo = apiClientService.getClient().getLoggedHeartRate(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()), fitbitUser, new LocalDate(year,month,day));
                //HeartRate heartAverage = new HeartRate(heartInfo.getTrackerAverage());                               
                request.setAttribute("heartRate", heartInfo);

                /*double weight = apiClientService.getClient().getWeight(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()), new FitbitUser("-"), new LocalDate(2012,5,5));
                request.setAttribute("weight", weight);*/

                // get BodyInfo (weight, fat, bmi) 
                Body bodyInfo = apiClientService.getClient().getBody(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()), fitbitUser, new LocalDate(year,month,day));
                //BodyWithGoals bodyGoals = apiClientService.getClient().getBodyWithGoals(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()), new FitbitUser("-"), new LocalDate(year,month,day));
                request.setAttribute("bodyInfo", bodyInfo);

                // get BloodPressure (BP) Info
                Bp bloodPressureInfo = apiClientService.getClient().getLoggedBp(new LocalUserDetail(resourceCredentials.getLocalUserId()), fitbitUser, new LocalDate(year,month,day));                
                request.setAttribute("bloodPressureInfo", bloodPressureInfo);

                // forward result to .jsp page
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/fitbitApiAuthExample.jsp").forward(request, response);
            } catch (FitbitAPIException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Exception during getting user info", e);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                response.sendRedirect(apiClientService.getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURL(new LocalUserDetail("-"), exampleBaseUrl + "/fitbitApiAuthExample?completeAuthorization="));
            } catch (FitbitAPIException e) {
                throw new ServletException("Exception during performing authorization", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your servlet code please

Comment: The error occured in your `getLoggedHeartRate` method, please provide the code. Also ensure that parameters are the expected ones.

Comment: I don't think error is in: getLoggedHeartRate, because it's an API from https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/Fitbit+Resource+Access+API and it should work. As I said, everything was wroking OK and suddenly I get there error and nothing worked anymore.

Comment: There is a problem only if I use debugger. Can be something wrong with Eclipse? What if I make new workspace again, can this help?

Comment: I you read the stacktrace you can see that the error come from this method. I think there is something wrong with the passed parameters?

Comment: Ok maybe I've an idea. Do you access some files with relative path? When you debug your project class are not in the same directory so path can fails. I don't use Eclipse but I experienced something similar using Netbeans debugger.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problem.

It was such strange (or stupid) mistake.

In breakpoints I had checked this: 
NullPointerException: caught and uncaught.
When I removed it it works everything ok again :)
Thanks for help!